# Reinforcement Learning Neuronal Networks

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning

Lets say I've a trained model of a Deep-Q-Learning Function. My ouputs are my actions. The network would look like this
[NN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcNLp.jpg)

I want to use the model. Would I run it like that: Give the network the state s1 as input(all other inputs are not in use) and look at my outputs. Take the output with the highest value and that is my action my agent has to take. Do the action and give him s2 as input without s1 and do the same thing

Comment: That sounds like the right way of using it... If there is a problem, could you share some more detail?

Comment: There is no problem with it. I just want to know if its the right way of using a model.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here's a diagram that shows the flow of Deep Q learning.
The inputs to the neural net are the factors that play into the "state". Based on the state, the NN will output a specified number of nodes, which are the actual-Q value pairs. If the agent is deciding which action to take, it will choose the node with the highest Q value, and in this case each node represents some certain action. Based on the action selected, the environment will generate a new state, that can again be used in the neural net.

[image: Depiction of DQN]

Answer (score 0):

Usually what's done in q-learning is the following:

- Start from a state s_1
- Feed a representation of the state to the model
- The output is the state-action value (value of taking action "a" from state "s_1"), so take the one with the highest one  (or randomly if training)
- The chosen action brings you to a new state s_2
- Repeat the process from s_2